# Sonar and Eclipse IAM Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sonarqube

When I am using the newest IAM Eclipse Plugin for Maven with the current Sonar version on a JDK 6 and I get an error while executing the `sonar:sonar` goal in

```
clean install sonar:sonar
```

The error in eclipse is

```
23:02:55 MESZ Starting Starting mojoExecution sonar-core:internal
23:03:44 MESZ fatal org.sonar.maven2.BatchMojo#execute() caused a linkage error (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError). Check the realms:
...
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
org.apache.maven.execution.ReactorManager.<init>(Ljava/util/List;)V
```

Any idea how to fix it?

PS: If I do a `mvn clean install sonar:sonar` manually this it not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems hard to say anything with the current level of detail (it's often preferable to mention the versions of the software you're using: Maven, the sonar plugin, the JDK). Anyway, my suggestion would be to try on the command line first (i.e. outside of Eclipse). If it doesn't work, update your question with your pom (the sonar plugin part), your maven version, the error trace (with more lines).

Comment: If I do a `mvn lean install sonar:sonar` manually this it not an issue.

Comment: @Hans Then there is very likely an issue with the IAM plugin. I suggest to run `sonar:sonar` on the command line (it's not common to run this goal from the IDE actually, the common use case is to run it from a continuous integration engine, daily).